# Internal component Linking on outbound email

Tags: outbound-email

I want to use existing components(Like News component, campaign components etc) for my newsletter mailings, and these components should point to the pages(respective detail pages) on which they have been linked as main components. Do I need to have custom link resolver for mailings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you track the Component Link (e.g. implicitly through the Post-processing TBB or explicitly by calling the GetLinkTrackingURL function), it will be resolved once people click on the link.

Basically, the link in the e-mail will point to the tracking URL you have configured on your Publication; said page will track the click action, call the Content Delivery Linking API to resolve the Component Link and redirect to the correct URL.

If there's a problem resolving the Component Link, it will instead redirect to the URL configured as the "ErrorResolvingLink" setting in cd_audience_manager_conf.xml.

Comment: Ok we are doing the tracking on links. Will test this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Peter, I also have to use component linking in newsletter. I am able to redirect to the component URL by using GetLinkTrackingURL function. But while I am using tracking implicitly. Then I think there should be no use of adding this function. But it is not working. I have verified I am using XHTML in my newsletter. Please suggest me I don't want to use  GetLinkTrackingURL function?

Comment: Are you saying that when you just set the Post-processing TBB to track all links, your Component Links are not working? Could you clarify what the problem is? Does it not change the Component Links at all? Or does it correctly point to the Tracking page, but then redirect you to the error page?